# CSS - background foreground contrast text color

Tags: css, text, colors, background, foreground

I have a bar column which is colored by percentage value.

[image]

Part of the text is not visible to the user since it is white and falls in the white section. If i select it i can see it but not otherwise-

[image]

Is there way in css to show the text in contrast to the background color? Maybe half the text is in white and half the text is in black, so it would be visible to the user.

Comment: Why can't you just manually set the colors you want to use? You could define style pairs like "darkBg" and "lightText" that work well together.

Comment: Why not just make the whole text `black`? It would be reasonably visible on both colors -- the greenish-cyan and red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```css
.progressbarContainer
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #ff00ff;
}
.backText
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: black;
}
.frontText
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
}
.progressbar
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 14.34%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbarContainer">
    <div class="backText">
        14.34%
    </div>
    <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="frontText">
        14.34%
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8VNT/)